# Kubernetes: Mongo container not creating

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes, microservices

I am unable to create a mongo container using a deployment:

*Persistent volume and persistent volume claims are working fine.*

```
> kubectl logs -f mongo-depl-dc764fb6d-qqdxh
Error from server (BadRequest): container "mongo" in pod "mongo-depl-dc764fb6d-qqdxh" is waiting to start: CreateContainerError
```

> **Persistent Volume :**

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: PersistentVolume 
metadata: 
  name: mongo-pv 
  labels: 
    type: local 
spec: 
  storageClassName: manual 
  capacity: 
    storage: 1Gi 
  accessModes: 
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath: 
    path: "E:\\Linux\\mongo"
```

> **Persistent Volume Claim :**

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata: 
  name: mongo-pvc 
spec: 
  storageClassName: manual 
  accessModes: 
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources: 
    requests: 
      storage: 0.5Gi
```

> **Mongodb Deployment** :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: mongo-depl
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: mongo
    template:
        metadata:
            labels: 
                app: mongo
        spec:
            volumes: 
                - name: mongo-volume 
                  persistentVolumeClaim: 
                    claimName: mongo-pvc 
            containers:
                - name: mongo
                  image: mongo:3.6.5-jessie 
                  ports:
                    - name: mongo 
                      containerPort: 27017
                  volumeMounts: 
                    - name: mongo-volume 
                      mountPath: /data/db 
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: mongo-srv
spec:
    type: NodePort
    selector:
        app: mongo
    ports:
        - name: mongo
          protocol: TCP
          port: 27017
          targetPort: 27017
```

I would really appreciate the help. I am running kubernetes on a dev environment on the windows machine.

Comment: `kubectl describe pod ...` might tell you more.  You can get an error like this if the named `hostPath:` doesn't exist on the node where the pod is ultimately scheduled.  You tagged this with GKE, and that comes with a dynamic volume provisioner; you can delete the `storageClass` and manual PersistentVolume, and let the cluster create it for you.

Comment: You can add the response of describe pod which is failing also in the question

Comment: ```Error: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /data/db``` This is the error showing in the describe output for some reason. I was able to use ```/data/db``` earlier when I was not using PersistentVolume and was directly using ```pvc```. But now that I am using ```persistentVolume```, I am getting this error!

Comment: Try `path: "/E/Linux/mongo"` and let me know if it works. Also check [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/59876#issuecomment-390452420)